# Wrapper hash function to return hash of wrapped type

Tags: c++, templates, hashtable

I have the following code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

// wrapper class on type E
template <typename E>
class g {
public:
    E val;
    g(E x) : val(x) {};
};

// hash for g<E> should be hash for E
template<typename E> struct std::hash<g<E>> { 
    std::size_t operator()(const ::g<E> &t) const { 
        return std::hash<E>()(t); 
    } 
};

int main() {
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false); cin.tie(nullptr);
    unordered_set<g<int>>{g<int>(3)};
}
```

Basically, the idea is that I have a wrapper around a templated type, and I want to be able to use this wrapper class in an unordered_set/map. But I get the following error:
`no match for call to '(std::hash<int>) (const g<int>&)'`. This is strange - doesn't c++ implement this hash? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Besides the problem Brian shows, you're also missing the unorderd_set requirement of equivalence check. I.e. a `g<E>` needs to be testable for direct equivalence against another. A simple const member `bool operator ==(const g<E>& arg) const` should provide that.

Comment: @WhozCraig Ah that's true, although I had omitted it for the sake of a minimal representation of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is attempting to invoke `std::hash<int>()` on `t`, which has type `g<int>`. You need to "unwrap" the wrapper and call `std::hash<int>()` on the enclosed `int`:

```
return std::hash<E>()(t.val);
```

Comment: Brian?????? You know, I saw your site just a couple months ago when looking for solutions to Artin - thanks for those! Anyways, thanks as well for this answer, silly mistake on my part.